# System.IndexOutOfRangeException error because of "material design lite"

Tags: asp.net, webforms, bundling-and-minification, material-design-lite, asp.net-bundling

I want to use https://material.io/ in my asp.net web project. I put it in the style.bundle and i get an this error: `System.IndexOutOfRangeException`

I removed **material.min.css** in bundling after that page was working but the design was broken.

I wonder to know how can we use material.min.css in bundling. Is it possible? What we need to change?

Here is file: https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.indigo-pink.min.css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, problem was style render is not working because of some unknown characters in material.min.css.

Solutions is upgrading web.optimization and webgrase packages in nuget.

I just upgraded WebGrase to 1.6 and problem solved.

I hope it helps to you.